# Connected network cable ==> USB Wi-Fi crashed

Tags: centos, wifi, network-interface, ethernet, networksetup

I have two computers running CentOS7, and connected to the internet (of an Android mobile WiFi AP) via two adapters USB Wi-Fi.

Trying to create a local wired network, I connected them with a rj45 patch cable. The Wi-Fi connection disappeared.
Even

```
ifconfig
```

shows just the wired and loopback interfaces.
How to solve this please?

- However, the LED on the USB Wi-Fi begins (and continue) to blink a few seconds after replugging it?...
- `iw list` gives

  `nl80211 not found`
- Reinstalled all the system, but still same problem. Seems like the WiFi capacities simply disappeared from the computer...

Comment: What about `ifconfig -a` or `ip link ls` ?

Comment: @derobert Nothing :-( ... Only shows loopback and eth.

Comment: Next thing to check would be the kernel messages, to see if there is anything there (`dmesg`, `journalctl -b -k`, `less /var/log/kern.log`, etc.). Also—just to make sure—you are talking about `ifconfig` on the machine with the USB WiFi plugged in, not the other machine, correct?

Comment: @derobert `dmesg` and `journalctl` given nothing. When replugging the device, there are just messages that it is recognised. And yes, exactly, this is on the Wi-Fi machine.

Comment: @derobert `cat /var/log/wpa_supplicant<today>.log` shows several messages that "failed to initiate AP scan", or "could not read interface wlp0s29f7u3 flags: no such device".

Comment: @derobert At least now I know the name of the WiFi interface. Trying `ifconfig wlp0s29.. up` given nothing.